# Executing mount command in Java on Android

Tags: java, terminal, root, sudo, mount

I'm trying to write Java code that executes some terminal commands. The code should execute this command `sudo mount -o loop system.img system`. But there are several problems. First, to execute this command I have to be `root`. I know that I can be by `sudo su`, but how can I stay as `root` when I close the terminal window? If I use the command `sudo mount -o loop system.img system` how can I provide the password in the Java code?

The second issue is: can I execute the command as below?

```
File f2 = new File("/home/user1/Desktop/aDirectory");
String[] commands = new String[]{"sudo mount", "-o", "loop", "/home/user1/Desktop/aDirectory/system.img"};

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands, null, f2);
```

I think I can't. So how can I do it? Any ideas?

**Notes:** `system.img` is a compiled *Android* os file. and the `system` is an empty directory. The thing I'm trying to do is mount the `system.img` file into the `system` directory.

Comment: Shouldn't the Strings in `commands` each have a space before or after them ?

Comment: I don't know. I'm really new at this stuff. But I think you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved, by using shell script.

I wrote a script includes just this line :

```
echo myPassword | sudo -S mount -o loop system.img system
```

then I run it in my java code, such :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh 1.sh");
```

Answer (score 1):

Programs like `sudo` read the password directly from the terminal device, not from `stdin`, so this is unfortunately not a trivial thing to do. I'm not sure if this is realistic for Android or not, but on a general UNIX system the easiest solution is to use [`expect`](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm), which is a library for simulating a terminal and thereby automating these kinds of interactions. It's often used as a standalone program embedded in `Tcl`, and I've thrown together systems in which Java launched `expect` to talk to tools like `sudo`, and it works fine.

`expect` includes a sort of declarative scripting language that tells it how to run another program and how to react to that program's output.

What you would do is use `Runtime.exec()` to execute the `expect` program, supplying a script that just runs "`sudo mount`", watches for the password prompt, and provides the password.  The script would probably just look something like (*G4rb4geB4rg3* is the password):

```
spawn sudo mount -o loop /home/user1/Desktop/aDirectory/system.img
expect "password:"
send "G4rb4geB4rg3\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: You mean programs like sudo? other than that seems plausible.

Comment: How should I use this `expect` with Java code? I'm afraid I couldn't get it. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure 'sudo' and 'mount' would be separate, since it's not a single executable you're invoking. Also, if you start sudo with the -S command line switch it can take the password directly from stdin, so you just need to start the process and pass in whatever the password's configured as to the input stream.